# How do I get the name of a parent struct in Swift?

Tags: swift

Let's say we had

```
struct Parent {
    struct Child {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can easily get the name of the child via `String(describing: type(of: child))`. Is the same possible for the outer/parent struct, knowing only the child?

Example: `"Parent"` or `"Parent.Child"`

Comment: Nope you can't. You also probably *shouldn't*, because "where I move this struct" is a strange/undesirable way of causing implicit coupling. What are you trying to do with this?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "parent struct" in Swift. Nesting types in Swift doesn't result in any connection between such types on the type system level. It only results in namespacing. The namespace of `Child` becomes `Parent.Child`, but its type is still just `Child` and its visibility isn't local to `Parent` either unlike in some other languages such as Java.

Comment: I see. My use case is that I need an API where users can define a large amount of "infrastructure" that interacts with native formats, and would have loved for my users to be able to just namespace certain structs which which all have the name of the parent struct in common. Guess I was trying to be too smart about it...

Comment: For your use case, `protocol` is seems a natural choice. It may not even have any functions or variables (like `Error` protocol, which is just empty), but it defines a common ground for anything your users may define. And you can check type / abstract on that level.